# How to continue with an IF and else using Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I need to continue in both cases. If false, continue and if true, run the GetSess... and continue.

The code below if UNKNOWN, execute and stops at else:. It ins`t in a loop.Have tried many ways to fix, but still not working.

(EDITED)

```
if gsid.find("OverAllDescription").text == 'UNKNOWN':
    GetSessId = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <OSS xmlns="http://www.zhone.com/OSSXML" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zhone.com/OSSXML ossxml.xsd"> <Request> <RequestType>authenticate</RequestType> </Request> <RequestElement> <Attribute> <Name>loginName</Name> <Value>zmstest</Value> </Attribute> <Attribute> <Name>password</Name> <Value>zmstest</Value> </Attribute> </RequestElement> </OSS>\n' 
    s.sendall(GetSessId.encode('utf-8'))
    response = s.recv(10240)
    print(response)
    gsidr = ET.fromstring(response)
    sessid = gsidr.findall("ResponseElement/SessionID")[0].text
    #print(sessid)
else:


code
```

I need something like:

If gsid != 'UNKNOWN'continue and If gsid == 'UNKNOWN', run GetSess… and continue.

Comment: How can it both be not equal to Unknown and equal to Unknown?

Comment: How can `gsid.find("OverAllDescription").text` be `!= 'UNKNOWN` and `== 'UNKNOWN'` at the same time?

Comment: It can be Unknown or SomethingElse, not both at the same time. The code "intent" is to ckeck and if Unknown, run some code and continue and if SomethingElse, just continue.

Comment: @F.Costa Your code checks `if gsid.find("OverAllDescription").text != 'UNKNOWN'` and then, inside that block, `if gsid.find("OverAllDescription").text == 'UNKNOWN'`. Essentially it's the same as `if gsid.find("OverAllDescription").text != 'UNKNOWN' and gsid.find("OverAllDescription").text == 'UNKNOWN'`

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying it:

```
if gsid.find("OverAllDescription").text == 'UNKNOWN':
    # Handle UNKNOWN case
else:
    # Handle non-UNKNOWN case
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if gsid.find("OverAllDescription").text != 'UNKNOWN':
     continue
else:
GetSessId = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <OSS xmlns="http://www.zhone.com/OSSXML" xmlns:xsi`enter code here`="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zhone.com/OSSXML ossxml.xsd"> <Request> <RequestType>authenticate</RequestType> </Request> <RequestElement> <Attribute> <Name>loginName</Name> <Value>zmstest</Value> </Attribute> <Attribute> <Name>password</Name> <Value>zmstest</Value> </Attribute> </RequestElement> </OSS>\n' 
            s.sendall(GetSessId.encode('utf-8'))
            response = s.recv(10240)
            #print(response)
            gsidr = ET.fromstring(response)
            sessid = gsidr.findall("ResponseElement/SessionID")[0].text
            #print(sessid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that code part of a **for** or **while** loop?

The **continue** statement is used to skip the rest of the code inside a loop for the current iteration only. Loop does not terminate but continues on with the next iteration.

For example, in a **for** loop:

```
for var in sequence:

    if gsid.find("OverAllDescription").text != 'UNKNOWN':
        continue

    if gsid.find("OverAllDescription").text == 'UNKNOWN':
        GetSessId = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <OSS xmlns="http://www.zhone.com/OSSXML" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zhone.com/OSSXML ossxml.xsd"> <Request> <RequestType>authenticate</RequestType> </Request> <RequestElement> <Attribute> <Name>loginName</Name> <Value>zmstest</Value> </Attribute> <Attribute> <Name>password</Name> <Value>zmstest</Value> </Attribute> </RequestElement> </OSS>\n' 
        s.sendall(GetSessId.encode('utf-8'))
        response = s.recv(10240)
        #print(response)
        gsidr = ET.fromstring(response)
        sessid = gsidr.findall("ResponseElement/SessionID")[0].text
        #print(sessid)
```

Or in a **while** loop:

```
while test expression:

    if gsid.find("OverAllDescription").text != 'UNKNOWN':
        continue

    if gsid.find("OverAllDescription").text == 'UNKNOWN':
        GetSessId = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <OSS xmlns="http://www.zhone.com/OSSXML" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zhone.com/OSSXML ossxml.xsd"> <Request> <RequestType>authenticate</RequestType> </Request> <RequestElement> <Attribute> <Name>loginName</Name> <Value>zmstest</Value> </Attribute> <Attribute> <Name>password</Name> <Value>zmstest</Value> </Attribute> </RequestElement> </OSS>\n' 
        s.sendall(GetSessId.encode('utf-8'))
        response = s.recv(10240)
        #print(response)
        gsidr = ET.fromstring(response)
        sessid = gsidr.findall("ResponseElement/SessionID")[0].text
        #print(sessid)
```